# How to persist .exe installations on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, python-tesseract

I am have created an Azure Cloud Service to analyze text in images. It uses [this Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) which depends on the installation of [Tesseract-OCR here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Downloads). Specifically, I am using `tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe` (one of the old versions because it has a Windows installer), which [can be found here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/).

**My problem is: this installer doesn't have a silent/automatic installation option, but I need it to automatically install itself when the Azure Cloud Service is being deployed.** I can't be manually installing it every time I upload the cloud service, and especially after Azure restarts the Cloud Service VM for maintenance. Are there other options for getting Tesseract-OCR installed on the Azure Cloud Service VM so that the installation persists if Azure restarts the Cloud Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to setup a VM, Install the software that you need, and deploy your app to this machine via ftp or something..

You can't customize the host of a "managed cloud service"